# Custom product template in satchmo

Tags: django, templates, satchmo

I'm implementing a store in satchmo.  I've created a custom product *MyProduct* by using model inheritance from the Product Model (as seen in http://thisismedium.com/tech/satchmo-diaries-part-one/).

Now I'd like to have a custom product detail template for *MyProduct*, and only *MyProduct*.  I tried creating a template in

```
/project/templates/product/product.html
```

But that overrides the template for ALL products in the store, not just *MyProduct*.  I also tried:

```
/project/templates/product/detail_myproduct.html
/project/templates/product/myproduct.html
```

But none of those seemed to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path with your first guess: templates/product/product.html.

If MyProduct is written like this:

```
class MyProduct(Product):
    # ...
    steele_level = model.IntegerField()

    objects = ProductManager()  # using this object manager is key!
```

And it is registered with the admin:

```
admin.site.regsiter(MyProduct)
```

Then you should be able to create a new MyProduct in the admin and then key off of a `myproduct` property on the product in product/product.html:

```
{% if product.myproduct %}
    This is a MyProduct with Steele Level: {{ product.myproduct.steele_level }}!
{% endif %}
```

Or if you prefer messing around in ./manage.py shell:

```
from project.models import MyProduct
from satchmo_store.shop.models import Product

for p in Product.objects.all():
    print p 
    if hasattr(p, 'myproduct'):
        print "  >>> That was a MyProduct with steele_level %s" % p.myproduct.steele_level
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  The only gotcha for me was that django went ahead and lowercased MyProduct.  So I needed to do product.myproduct (just like you wrote), instead of copying my model name product.MyProduct.